# problem to calculate gradient using GradientTape() of tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow

Using tensorflow 2.0 and GradientTape() function, the first tape.gradient() gives correct gradient tensor, But the second tape.gradient() gives 'None'.
Why the second value is 'None'? I expect the gradient computed respectively on a second.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.constant([ [1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0] ])
y0 = tf.constant([ [4.0], [8.0], [12.0] ])

w = tf.Variable( [[1.0], [1.0]] ) 

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y = tf.matmul(x, w)
    print("y : ", y.numpy())
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(y-y0)
    print("loss : ", loss.numpy())

grad = tape.gradient(loss, w)    # gradient calculation is correct
print("gradient : ", grad.numpy())

mu = 0.01
w = w - mu*grad

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y = tf.matmul(x, w)
    print("y : ", y.numpy())
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(y-y0)
    print("loss : ", loss.numpy())

grad = tape.gradient(loss, w)    # gradient value go to 'None'
print("gradient : ", grad)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `w` by a `Tensor` (which is *not* a `Variable`) by assigning `w = w - mu*grad`. By default, `GradientTape` only tracks variables. You have two options.

1. Recommended: Replace `w = w - mu*grad` by `w.assign(w - mu*grad)`. This keeps `w` as a `Variable` and is the way to update variable values.
2. You can track non-variables explicitly in a `GradientTape`. In the second tape context, add `tape.watch(w)` in the very beginning (before the `matmul`).