# TensorFlow 2.0 : ValueError - No Gradients Provided (After Modifying DDPG Actor)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

**Background**

I'm currently trying to implement a DDPG framework to control a simple car agent. At first, the car agent would only need to learn how to reach the end of a straight path as quickly as possible by adjusting its acceleration. This task was simple enough, so I decided to introduce an additional steering action as well. I updated my observation and action spaces accordingly.

The lines below are the for loop that runs each episode:

```
for i in range(episodes):
    observation = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0
    while not done:
        action = agent.choose_action(observation, evaluate)
        observation_, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score += reward
        agent.remember(observation, action, reward, observation_, done)
        if not load_checkpoint:
            agent.learn()
        observation = observation_
```

The lines below are my *choose_action* and *learn* functions:

```
def choose_action(self, observation, evaluate=False):
    state = tf.convert_to_tensor([observation], dtype=tf.float32)
    actions = self.actor(state)
    if not evaluate:
        actions += tf.random.normal(shape=[self.n_actions],
                mean=0.0, stddev=self.noise)
    actions = tf.clip_by_value(actions, self.min_action, self.max_action)

    return actions[0]

def learn(self):
    if self.memory.mem_cntr < self.batch_size:
        return

    state, action, reward, new_state, done = \
            self.memory.sample_buffer(self.batch_size)

    states = tf.convert_to_tensor(state, dtype=tf.float32)
    states_ = tf.convert_to_tensor(new_state, dtype=tf.float32)
    rewards = tf.convert_to_tensor(reward, dtype=tf.float32)
    actions = tf.convert_to_tensor(action, dtype=tf.float32)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        target_actions = self.target_actor(states_)
        critic_value_ = tf.squeeze(self.target_critic(
                            states_, target_actions), 1)
        critic_value = tf.squeeze(self.critic(states, actions), 1)
        target = reward + self.gamma*critic_value_*(1-done)
        critic_loss = keras.losses.MSE(target, critic_value)

    critic_network_gradient = tape.gradient(critic_loss,
                                        self.critic.trainable_variables)
    self.critic.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(
        critic_network_gradient, self.critic.trainable_variables))

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        new_policy_actions = self.actor(states)
        actor_loss = -self.critic(states, new_policy_actions)
        actor_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(actor_loss)

    actor_network_gradient = tape.gradient(actor_loss, 
                                self.actor.trainable_variables)
    self.actor.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(
        actor_network_gradient, self.actor.trainable_variables))

    self.update_network_parameters()
```

And finally, my *ActorNetwork* is as follows:

```
class ActorNetwork(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, fc1_dims=512, fc2_dims=512, n_actions=2, name='actor',
            chkpt_dir='tmp/ddpg'):
        super(ActorNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1_dims = fc1_dims
        self.fc2_dims = fc2_dims
        self.n_actions = n_actions

        self.model_name = name
        self.checkpoint_dir = chkpt_dir
        self.checkpoint_file = os.path.join(self.checkpoint_dir, 
                    self.model_name+'_ddpg.h5')

        self.fc1 = Dense(self.fc1_dims, activation='relu')
        self.fc2 = Dense(self.fc2_dims, activation='relu')
        self.mu = Dense(self.n_actions, activation='tanh')

    def call(self, state):
        prob = self.fc1(state)
        prob = self.fc2(prob)

        mu = self.mu(prob) * 3.5 

        return mu
```

*Note: The code I'm working with is just building off of the code from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jh32CvwKYw&t=835s)*

**The Problem**

Up until now, I hadn't faced any issues with the code but I did want to adjust the maximum/minimum values of my actions. When I was only considering the acceleration action, I simply multiplied mu by 3.5. However, I wanted the steering actions to exist within a range of -30 to 30 degrees, but I couldn't just multiply mu as I had before. To try to adjust the desired steering range, I made the following (not so elegant) changes to my *ActorNetwork*

```
def call(self, state):
    prob = self.fc1(state)
    prob = self.fc2(prob)

    mu = self.mu(prob)# * 3.5
    mu_ = []
    mu_l = mu.numpy().tolist()
    
    for i, elem1 in enumerate(mu_l):
        temp_ = []
        for j, elem2 in enumerate(elem1):
            if j-1 == 0:
                temp_.append(float(elem2 * 3.5))
            else:
                temp_.append(float(elem2 * math.radians(30)))
        mu_.append(temp_)
        
    mu = tf.convert_to_tensor(mu_, dtype=tf.float32)
    
    return mu
```

The new lines that I added were meant to:

1. Convert the mu tensor into a list
2. Iterate through the elements in the mu list (mu_l) and if a value had an index of 0 (acceleration) then multiply by 3.5; otherwise, multiply the value at index=1 (steering) by the radians conversion of 30 degrees.
3. Append each adjusted value into a new list (mu_)
4. Set mu to be equal to a tensor conversion of mu_

It was at this point that I ran into the following error:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['actor_network/dense/kernel:0', 'actor_network/dense/bias:0', 'actor_network/dense_1/kernel:0', 'actor_network/dense_1/bias:0', 'actor_network/dense_2/kernel:0', 'actor_network/dense_2/bias:0'].

I have tried to find solutions provided within StackOverflow and from outside sources (e.g. including watch, checking to make sure that I am using model() instead of model.predict() while in GradientTape(), making sure I'm not performing calculations outside of the Tape context) but I haven't had any luck resolving the issue. I suspect that my issue is similar to the one presented in [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57800189/problem-to-calculate-gradient-using-gradienttape-of-tensorflow-2-0) but I'm not sure how to diagnose whether my problem stems from also overwritting mu with a tensor. Does anyone have any insight regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved thanks to some simple but helpful advice I [received on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/nsywuy/gradienttape_returns_none_values_no_gradients/). I was disrupting the tracking of my variables by making changes using my custom for-loop. I should have used a TensorFlow function instead. The following changes fixed the problem for me:

```
def call(self, state):
    prob = self.fc1(state)
    prob = self.fc2(prob)

    mu = self.mu(prob)
    mult = tf.convert_to_tensor([3.5, math.radians(30)], dtype=tf.float32)
    mu = tf.math.multiply(mu, mult)
    
    return mu
```